# Internal Error:... ambiguous reference: 'DataGrid' is defined in library web/DataGrid.dart and also in web/out/DataGrid.dart

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I created a bare-bones datagrid using web-ui for testing and had it working just fine.  Then I decided to try to declare it as a component.  I changed around the library references and now it is giving me the above error when I try to run the application.  You can see my file structure below.  The reason I am getting the "ambiguous reference" message when I try to run it is that when I went into the auto-generated DataGrid.dart file in the out directory, it had the following declaration

```
import 'DataGrid.dart';
...
import '../DataGrid.dart';
```

I am confused as to why the generated code imports them both.  One thing that I considered is that it could be because the DataGridPage.html file instantiates my DataGrid component and my DataGridPage.dart file imports DataGrid.dart so that it can have references to DataGridColumn (it needs to set the columns for the DataGrid).  In DataGridPage.dart, I also attach to certain DataGrid events such as SortColumnChanged and SelectionChanged so I need to request a copy of my DataGrid instance in DataGridPage.dart (I don't think there is a way to attach to events from the web component instantiation in DataGridPage.html).

Any ideas about what I am doing wrong?

Here is my file structure:

```
DataGrid.dart
--------------------------------------------
library datagrid;
...
part 'DataGridColumn.dart';
part 'DataGridRow.dart';
class DataGrid extends WebComponent{...}    

DataGridRow.dart
--------------------------------------------
part of datagrid;
class DataGridRow {...}

DataGridColumn.dart
--------------------------------------------
part of datagrid;
class DataGridColumn {...}

DataGrid.html
--------------------------------------------
[contains the component declaration UI]

DataGridPage.html
-----------------------------------------
...
<div is="s-datagrid" id="myDataGrid" ItemsSource="{{app.Assets}}" Columns="{{app.Columns}}"></div>
...

DataGridPage.dart
--------------------------------------------
import 'DataGrid.dart';
import 'Asset.dart';
void main() {
}
DataGridApp _app;
DataGridApp get app {
  if (_app == null) {
    _app = new DataGridApp();
  }
  return _app;
}
class DataGridApp{
//provides ItemsSource and DataGridColumn data
}
```

Comment: I verified the same behavior with the default "Web UI Application" xclickcounter.  If you try import 'xclickcounter.dart' in the main dart file, when you run it it gives the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

jmesserly has answered this on the github site. He said that you need to remove the component import in your main dart file. So in my example I would remove the import 'DataGrid.dart' statement from the DataGridPage.dart. The IDE will give you a warning but you can ignore it because it will actually be run from the out folder.

[GitHub Web-UI Issue 342](http://github.com/dart-lang/web-ui/issues/342)